# Join 3 Tables with 3rd Table not associated to Table 2

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to Do the following:-

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.a, t2.b, t3.a, t3.b, t3.c 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.b = t2.b 
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.b <> t3.b 
WHERE t3.c = 'someuser'
```

Result:- I am getting rows of t2 associated in t3

Expected Result:- Get rows of t2 NOT associated in t3

### Pls help. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and results so we have some idea what you are asking?

Comment: Sample data is included now.

Comment: . . You included sample code.  I, for one, still have no idea what "not associated" means.  Provide a few rows of data and the results you want to get.

Comment: what do you mean by not associated? Rows of t2 not appearing in t3?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong Frank, but you want rows from t1 and t2 that match, but don't have an associated record in t3?  The answer I provided below was done with that assumption.

Comment: Yes correct I want t1 and t2 match but don't have any record in t3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember a left join that has non-matching records will result in null data in `t3`.  I changed the last two lines.  Try this:

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.a, t2.b, t3.a, t3.b, t3.c 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.b = t2.b 
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.b = t3.b 
WHERE t3.c = 'someuser' and t3.b is null
```

Although, if you're doing a conditional check on t3, it's always going to be false (when not checking for null)...

Maybe you want this?

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.a, t2.b, t3.a, t3.b, t3.c 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.b = t2.b 
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.b = t3.b and t3.c = 'someuser'
WHERE t3.b is null
```

The difference between the two queries is: the first one should always return 0 rows since you're expecting t3.b to be null (which MAY indicate that the joined table has no matching records) but then you check t3.c for a value which will never exist in the results.  The second query filters on t3.c during the join, and then in your WHERE clause you find null matches, which should hopefully indicate that there was no match (depending on how your data is setup).

Comment: can you explain how the two queries are different? I think it's worth being added.

Comment: Thanks but Query (2) gives the same result as displaying rows of t2 associated in t3. Query(1) did not show any result at all.

Comment: @didierc the second one is only trying to join records from t3 where t3.c = someuser and t2.b = t3.b and then the where clause will filter out the ones that aren't null.  In the first example t3.c will always be null and never return any rows since one condition is looking for a value and the other one is looking for no value on the same join.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean for me, but for completeness of the answer.

Comment: @FrankNwoko the second query shouldn't be showing rows that have matches between t2 and t3.  t3.b should be null on a LEFT OUTER join (or LEFT JOIN) if there wasn't a match.  Double check your data...

Comment: Btw, in your select list, you're select t3.a, t3.b, t3.c which will always be null in this scenario.  Try changing it to select * and running it in the mysql client to get a better visualization of the results.

Comment: UPdate: It gives desired result if I remove (and t3.c = 'someuser') in the second query. But I need to filter by the current user.

Comment: And the user is only contained in t3?  You can't check for that on t1 or t2 anyway?  Perhaps could you post some of the data you're trying to work with as a sample, or give us a better understanding of the scenario you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes the user is contained in t3. t1 contains Form Fields, t2 contains Form Fields associated with a particular event and t3 contains Users form details. I want to check for empty user profile data(t3) which MUST be completed for added event form fields(t2).

Comment: So are you trying to show rows that DON'T have that user in it?  Or that does have the user in it?  Try the last example with `<> 'someuser'` instead of `= 'someuser'` perhaps...

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU EVERYBODY. SOLVED IT.!

Comment: SOLUTION:- -----------------------------------------------------SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.a, t2.b, t3.a, t3.b, t3.c 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.b = t2.b 
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.b = t3.b and t3.c = 'someuser'
WHERE t3.b is null GROUP BY t3.c

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.a, t2.b, t3.a, t3.b, t3.c 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.b = t2.b 
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.b = t3.b and t3.c = 'someuser'
WHERE t3.b is null GROUP BY t3.c
```